# AngularJS validation for bootstrap state picker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, validation

I am using bootstrap country state picker but I can't validate it using AngularJS validation is there any possible solutions for it ??

Comment: How about adding more detail, adding your code, spending some time asking an understandable question, and correct typos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a *directive* as your custom validation

```
app.directive('state', function() {
  var states = [
    "Sweden",
    "England",
    "Denmark"
  ]

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.state = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue))
            return false;

        if (jQuery.inArray(viewValue, states) > -1)
            return true;

        return false;
        }
    }
  };
});
```

Example Html

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <select state ng-model="states" class="form-control">
        <option>Sweden</option>
        <option>England</option>
        <option>Denmark</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="form.states.$error.state">Not a state</span>
</form>
```

Checkout Angular's docs for more info
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

**Remember that validation is more important on your BE** and in this case probably not to hard. Cheers!